# Launch controller method with Click Event WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I would like to know how I can directly call a method of my controller from "Click" event button in my view without put code in my view

```
<Button Click="?"/>
```

I don't want to generate a method in my view just to call another method (Unless i have to).

Thanks

Comment: I suggest looking into commands: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands are the usual answer to this problem.  Unfortunately it takes a little boilerplate to get going, here is a really simple example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyCommand ButtonClick { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        ButtonClick = new MyCommand();
        ButtonClick.CanExecuteFunc = ButtonClickCanExecute;
        ButtonClick.ExecuteFunc = ButtonClickFunc;
    }

    public bool ButtonClickCanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void ButtonClickFunc(object parameter)
    {
        // Do stuff here 
    }

}

public class MyCommand : ICommand 
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public Predicate<object> CanExecuteFunc { get; set; }
    public Action<object> ExecuteFunc { get; set; }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return CanExecuteFunc(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        ExecuteFunc(parameter);
    }
}
```

You can add more logic into the `CanExecute` besides return true if you like, then you can just reuse the `MyCommand` class for any other commands you have going on in your UI.  To bind your button you just need to write simply:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ButtonClick}">Action</Button>
```

Comment: What is   ButtonClick.CanExecuteFunc = obj => true; ?

Comment: Commands need to have a function to run to determine whether the command can be executed (which translates into whether the button is enabled), in this case that function is just an anonymous method that returns true.  I'll edit it to make it a little more clear if you aren't used to lambda syntax.

Comment: ButtonClick.CanExecuteFunc cannot be set directly at true ?

Comment: No, the can execute method is a function, since theoretically it could evaluate differently at different times, such as whether a user has a certain item selected.  It seems a bit silly when you just always want it enabled, but it allows you to have a lot of power in other cases.